# an lcd with I2C is not recognized by esp32

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, esp32, lcd

I have a NodeMCU esp32-s board and I'm trying to connect My 16x2 lcd with PCF8574T I2C bus to the esp32 , the problem is that the lcd doesn't show anything and the WireScan sketch can't recognize the lcd too,but when I use arduion uno ,it's recognized and work perfectly ,I hope somebody can help me,the schematic for the connection is :
[image]

the schematic for the connection of the lcd with the bus is below with the bus module part number [image]:

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: What things need to be cleared?

Comment: you need to make it clear how the LCD is connected and, most importantly, which LCD you are using ... right now, all we know which pins are connected at the ESP32 ... we know nothing else ... also, you have not asked a question about the problem

Comment: well,if you return back to my question you see I have mentioned the type and part number and this is exactly the problem, I can't provide more.

Comment: the PCF8574T is an IC that is part of the LCD ... it is an I2C bus expander ... which component is used in the display module has no bearing on the connector pinout of the LCD module

Comment: ok , thanks , I have just edited the question , please let me know if it is clear now or not.

Comment: Can you verify 5 VDC and ground are present at the I2C, LCD backpack? How are you powering the ESP32?

Comment: yes they exist and they are named as VDD and VSS , also the two parts are soldered together and the lcd is lighting when using esp32.

Comment: Do the ESP32 GIOPs operate at 3.3 VDC? You may need a logic level converter of some type on the I2C lines. For example: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003157047080.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.74f168cfuMUXE9&algo_pvid=581ce205-0f3f-42bc-8d30-a719047333f2&algo_exp_id=581ce205-0f3f-42bc-8d30-a719047333f2-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000024404763535%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21CAD%212.39%212.16%21%21%21%21%21%40211bc2a016760709924762576d06d7%2112000024404763535%21sea%21CA%21915735244&curPageLogUid=y2eJwfSkV6yg

Comment: I'm using the 5v pin to power the I2C module , but SDA and SCL pins are powered with GPIO pins which I think they are providing 3.3v.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the PCF8574 on 5V and the EXP on 3V3 just be sure the I2C is pulled up to the 3V3 and NOT the 5V. I do this a lot and have never had a problem. The reason it works is the bus is driven by open collector/drain drivers which do not source any voltage.